# Calling rake task on web request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

In my Rails app, the user can upload a file and then what I need to do is: when the file is uploaded I want to start a rake task, which parses the file and feeds all the tables in the database, and depending on how large is the file, it can take some time. I assume sth like >> system "rake task_name" in my controller will do the work.

However is it the best practice? Is it safe? Because in that way any user would be starting a rake process. In this [Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background) they recommend running rake in background. What would be an alternative or the common practice?

Comment: Why not just run a rake task every five minutes which checks for new files, and processes them as needed? Another option is using ActiveJob or some other background processing library.

Comment: Better practice would be a delayed/asynchronous job. Basically the upload triggers a Job, which is handled by a worker. I can think of a few other ways to skin this cat.

Comment: I was trying to do the Active Job idea. Active Job works only with Rails 4, I use Rails 3.2 for this app. I will try [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Rails 3.2, so I couldn't use Active Job. I used Sidekiq and worked fine.
Check a very helpful tutorial [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq?view=asciicast)